# Get current focus dynamically with angular.element function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, focus, element

I'm trying to get the current input focus dinamically with angular and typescript.
I'm using the *angular.element([selector]).focus(handler)* function but it does not trigger when i click on an input.

This is my code:

```
class TemplateController {
    lastFocused: HTMLInputElement;

    static $inject = ['$scope'];
    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {

        angular.element("input[type='text']").focus((): void => {
            this.lastFocused = document.activeElement as HTMLInputElement;
            console.log("FOCUSED");
        });
    }
}

angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("[...]templateController", TemplateController);
}
```

And this is my html (input snippet):

```
...

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" size="30" ng-maxlength="1000" required />

...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT: Solved**

I was able to solve this problem by using *ng-focus* attribute on the input element:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" size="30" ng-maxlength="1000" required ng-focus="templateCtrl.setFocusedElement()" />
```

and inside the controller:

```
setFocusedElement(): void {
    this.$scope.lastFocused = document.activeElement;
}
```

This works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

`angular.element('input').triggerHandler('focus');`

or if it doesn't work

`angular.element('input').triggerHandler('click');`